# Cannot access BIOS (UEFI) through normal means

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, motherboard, uefi

So I just build my first custom PC [[PCPartpicker](https://pcpartpicker.com/user/Cat_Gamer23/saved/43Vt7P)]

I was able to boot into bios when I first started it up, but after installing windows 10 pro, I am unable to access it again. I've tried both the normal press F2/Del key, (as specified by user manual for mobo) and from windows recovery. However, neither goes into bios, it just boots like normal. However, if I reflash the motherboard's bios, I'm able to access it once. I've also tried power cycling the pc, which doesn't work.

So how do I access the bios??

Edit: I have disabled fast boot in bios, and fast startup in windows. I also am using the latest bios version (I tried 3 other versions also), Cleared CMOS, I've tried the holding shift key and shutting down, and my keyboard and HDMI cable are directly connected.

Also, don't know if its related, but my PC doesn't display anything until it's the windows login screen.

Also my PC has a 640x480 resolution until I turn of the TV, and turn it back on. Then it goes into its 1920x1080p resolution. Something about a broken EDID info?

Edit: I've found something that seems to partially work. If I enable CSM, it works for a few reboots, then breaks again. If I change it to UEFI only, it works again, then I have to change to UEFI and Legacy OPROM mode and continue to alternate.

Comment: Hold the shift key down when you click Restart.

Comment: Is there any firmware (BIOS/UEFI) update available for the board? What if you disconnect all drives and retry entering BIOS during POST? Are you using any USB hubs to connect Keyboard? What if you run a Live Linux or some third-party Windows PE bootable USB and restart from there and check again? What if you reset BIOS to defaults by shorting the two pins on mobo meant for the same when PC is completely off and try again?

Comment: Try enabling Legacy (CSM) Boot Mode in BIOS (If provided) and check again. It does not mean you are switching to Legacy, it just means in addition to UEFI mode, CSM is also available.

Comment: Also my PC has a 640x480 resolution until I turn of the TV,    ....   Make sure only one monitor is attached.

Comment: @patkim ill try to enable csm tomorrow when i am able to access my pc.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning Windows 10 Fast Start OFF (System Properties  or in your Power Plan Settings).

Then start the machine and let it run for a few minutes.

Now, Restart (not shutdown). Restart tends to be slower (at least on the machines I use).

On two of my machines, on Restart, there is a screen message saying "Press enter to interrupt startup".  Watch for a message like this. There may not be one but do check.

As soon as it begins to start, press F2 repeatedly until BIOS (UEFI) begins.

Restart and repeated presses of the BIOS access key almost always works for me.

[image: Win10 Fast Start setting]